# Why doesn't this sub navigation element fill the entire area?

Tags: html, css

I've tried everything I can do get the "Rentals" element to fill the entire width of the dropdown menu, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas? I've tried modifying widths, using nowrap, etc... nothing seems to work (ps. this is part of a custom responsive design so if something seems out of place it might be because I'm resetting something that was previously defined)

```css
nav ul {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Raleway, Arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 10;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: inline;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
nav ul a:hover,
nav ul a:active {
  background-color: #9a1414;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="search.php">Search</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="search.php">Search MLS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="search-commercial.php">Commercial</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="search-rentals.php">Rentals</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="agents.php">Agents</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="property-management.php">Property Management</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="open-houses.php">Open Houses</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="local.php">Local</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: you could try to use letter-spacing property just on that one. But if you ask me , having just one menu in the dropdown having a wider letter  spacing might end up looking odd

Comment: Could you please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or link to a live version of your site?

Comment: I figured it out. Because i had:

    nav ul ul li {
        float: left;
    }

it was messing around with something (not sure why it stops it from working, but it does). I also added display: block to the <a> nav ul ul a element